# Best way to get "last blow/killing hit" in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I find it difficult to get my shot on the creeps so that to get the "last killing hit/blow".

I guess the problem is that the champion's attack is automatically ONLY when he/she stops - that's the tricky truth makes it hard to hit last.

I notice that in the "Game" menu, we can config to turn off "automatic attack". Though, that's *not* good to me since in most situation I want my champions attack on their own.

So my question is how can we make life easier to get "last hit"?

Comment: "Creeps" are you sure you are playing LoL here? Are they not called minions?

Comment: @DavidToh Yes, they are minion. I call `creep` as the habit in Dota in the past

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that all your problems arise from standing still.

I think you are saying that you find it difficult to last hit because when you stop moving your champion will automatically attack. You can stop this by pushing "s" which will stop your champion from moving **and** stop them from automatically attacking until another command is issued. So you can push s and then when the time is right attack for the last hit on a minion.

A better alternative however is to constantly stay in motion, move back and forth, side to side and attack the minions when you need to. This has the advantage of making it harder for your opponent to hit you with autos or skills and also makes it possible for you to manoeuvre into positions from where you can safely attack and harass your opponent.

Aside from that, it just takes practice. Of course you can also make it slightly easier by having flat damage runes but it always comes down to practice as you'll have to last hit on low ad champions like lux as well.

One thing that may help is to note your AD and then note what the minions health bar looks like when their hp is below your ad. As you're not going to be clicking on every minion to see their health this can be useful for helping you get used to what a killable minion's health bar looks like. Remember that the ranged minions, melee minions and siege minions all have different amounts of hp all of which scales throughout the game.

Comment: Press `s` to stop attacking is all what I need. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

The best way to practice last hitting is in custom games play an adc and use ~10 less starting ad then you would have in a real game

Only go for last hit or a necessary shot to set one up (so you can't just auto attack the ranged creeps down)

Always try to get the hits from max range

Don't use abilities (practice flash farm with abilities separately)

And keep moving all the time

Play up to 5 min (game time) and rate your cs out of 30. (assuming you don't attack 4:30 spawns)

Comment: What is `cs` in full?

Comment: creep score - the amount of creeps ( minions ) you've last hit.
you can see the League of Legends terminology for any further question you might have
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_terminology

Comment: May you explain more on your `hits from max range` advice?

Comment: Yeah. the reason for that is since you're training in a custom game with no enemy heroes you can easily move around the lane, but in a real game you won't be able to due to pressure from your lane opponent. practice as if it's an actually game

Comment: You can also put a bot with a ranged attack against you. Some of them harass and farm quite well. As an extra rule: do not hit the enemy at all. This way you have to play against something that slightly shoves your lane and harasses you.